# Chess Tournament Probability Problem Explanation

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

I am reading the book Introduction to Probability by Dimitri Bertsekas and John Tsitsiklis Athena Scientific 2nd edition 2008 and I stumbled upon a probabilistic model problem and I can't seem to understand the answer to it. It goes as follows:

> You enter a special kind of chess tournament, in which you play one
>   game with each of three opponents, but you get to choose the order in
>   which you play your opponents, knowing the probability of a win
>   against each. You win the tournament if you win two games in a row,
>   and you want to maximize the probability of winning. Show that it is
>   optimal to play the weakest opponent second, and that the order of
>   playing the other two opponents does not matter.

I don't get it. Why is it optimal to play the weakest opponent second? Why should I wait to use my best chances to a win? And after I do that, why is it that the order of the other two guys is not relevant?

Comment: "Model theory" refers to a specific branch of mathematical logic (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) or read the tag description), which is apparently unrelated to the question, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: Go through the different possibilities of whether you win or lose each game (8 options) and evaluate whether or not you won the tournament

Comment: Short intuitive answer: In a 3-game-long tournament, if you need to win two games *in a row*, then the middle game is more important (indeed, it's a must-win).